# How to retrieve the default color of a calendar using EWS SOAP API

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using the below XML to fetch my calendars. The response contains some of the details of my calendars but doesn't contain the default color for calendars. I also want to get the default color set for each calendar. How do I get it?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindFolder Traversal="Deep">
      <m:FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
      </m:FolderShape>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar" />
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindFolder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Comment: I think you need access to the Master Category List [like this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e5c5f072-0b5c-49ce-9db7-57f76f5e011e/edit-master-category-list-in-exchange-2010-via-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment). Category options are stored as [Folder Associated Items (FAIs)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/98b92409-7bc7-4005-b6be-e32bdbc1cce0/where-does-outlook-store-auxiliary-mailbox-data?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment).

Comment: You can search the Exchange dev forum for [Folder associated items](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment&sort=relevancedesc&brandIgnore=True&searchTerm=Folder+Associated+Item) or for [FAI](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment&brandIgnore=True&sort=relevancedesc&searchTerm=FAI).

Comment: Here are [two](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c6bad155-33b7-40a6-90d6-58f6803d19be/accessing-folder-associated-items-for-all-mailboxes-ex2007-and-2003?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) [more](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2008/05/22/Working-with-the-MasterCategoryList-Via-WebDAV.aspx) articles. This is how far my knowledge goes, I never actually had to use this, only researched it lightly. I remember another post improving on the infinitec one, you'll have to search for it.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: I concluded that it is not possible.